# Placing a MySQL variable inside <img src"xxxxx">

Tags: php, html, mysql

This might sound a little vague, but I'm looking to place a variable from a MySQL database inside a line of HTML. Currently it looks like this:

[image: hi].

Below is the code I am using.
Thanks!

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Helo</th> <th>Class</th> <th>Need</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['Icon'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['Class'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['Need'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: I'm looking to turn the Helo column into an image when displayed

Comment: tables + mysql_query + echoing out html...so much awesomeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['Helo'].'" title="'.$row['Class'].'">';
```